# Comparing objects using isinstanceOf

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use the isInstanceOf operator to get a value from a tuple and checking whether its of a specific type. I'm scratching my head over the error and I don't want to use match cases.

```
val t = ("ww",2, 3.4)

if(t._1 isInstanceOf[String])
  println("yes")
```

The error I get is:

```
<console>:1: error: type application is not allowed for postfix operators
```

Comment: The compiler knows all the element types of a `Tuple`.  If you're using `isInstanceOf` to test a tuple at runtime then there's a flaw in your design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing dot `.`

Corrected

```
if(t._1.isInstanceOf[String]) println("yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a dot between the variable and isInstanceOf:

```
if (t._1.isInstanceOf[String])
```

Your notation without the dot, as a postfix operator, is not allowed because the function takes a type parameter (`String`). I don't know exactly why this precludes postfix notation but I guess it's just too hard to parse.